# A-Team Mobile Persistence Accelerator extension is missing after installation

Tags: mobile, persistence, oracle-maf

I had successfully (read as without any problem) installed the A-Team Mobile Persistence Accelerator by following the instructions in the article "Getting Started with the A-Team Mobile Persistence Accelerator" and I could easily go up to the point of restarting the Jdeveloper. But I do not find the "Adf Mobile" category under Business Tier. I also don't find it under Help->About-Extensions -> search for "A-team ..". What am I missing?

The zip file created by  DesignTime->build->Run Ant on DesignTime.jpr had successfully created "mobile-persistence-master/Projects/Framework/stage/ateam-mobile-persistence.12.1.3.0.57-install.zip". I had selected this file and installed under "Install from local file" and then restarted the Jdeveloper. But as expected after the installation step (from local install file),  I do not find the "ADF Mobile" category in the New Gallery under Business Tier. This is happening inspite of doing the steps a couple of times/restarting the Jdeveloper/machine

I am using Mac OSx 10.9.5 
Jdevelper 12.1.3.0 
Mobile Application Framework 2.0.0.0.41.14023.0901 (Triggers Loaded)

Comment: Do you see A-Team Mobile Accelerator read-me file after finishing installation and restarting Jdeveloper?

Comment: No, That is the problem. I dont see that. But everythibg gies. I have restarted it no results. The Help-extension does not show it too.

Comment: BTW I am using MAx OSx 10.9